# HTML5 Android XDK App appears zoomed in on some phones

Tags: android, html, cordova, intel, intel-xdk

I am currently using intel XDK to build a HTML5 android app. App files were created with Cordova command prompt, and HTML assets was done using JQuerymobile. Files were transfered to Intel XDK for the building process and apk was obtained. However, when I install the app on some phones (Samsung Note3, Android 4.3) it appears the page is zoomed in, and displays like when you try accessing a non-responsive desktop website using a phone.

However, when I installed same app on A Samsung S5 (Android 5.0), the app displays properly the way it should be.

How can i fix this? will the meta viewport tag help? See attached screenshots. Kindly help please.

[This is how it appears on the Samsung Note 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJejj.png)

[This is how it appears on the Samsung S5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnN35.jpg)

This is the current viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

Try building using the ["Crosswalk for Android"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/why-use-crosswalk-for-android-builds) build, this will embed a more advanced runtime with the app. This will give you consistent appearance and performance regardless of the Android device version.

Comment: Yes, that may solve the problem, but Crosswalk adds an additional about 20mb to the overall size of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the target-densitydpi did the trick.
Change from target-densitydpi=device-dpi to target-densitydpi=medium-dpi or remove altogether.